# Appending data column wise using R

Tags: r

I am running a loop in R and every run gives me a dataframe with two variables - Timestamp and Rainfall (as shown below).

```
    Timestamp,Rainfall_Region 1  
    01/01/2007 00:15,0.01
    01/01/2007 00:30,0.04
    --------------------------
    --------------------------
```

The loop runs 500 times and I want to create a text file in the format below-

```
    Timestamp,Rainfall_Region 1, Rainfall_Region 2,...... 
    01/01/2007 00:15,0.01,0.03,.........
    01/01/2007 00:30,0.04,0.06,.........
    --------------------------
    --------------------------
```

The total number of records are more than a million and I cannot use cbind to create one big dataframe in R and then export it. Is there a way to do this in R or otherwise? Timestamp is the common variable among all dataframes. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Create a data frame with same number of rows as the total number of iterations. Also with the same number of variables and type, and then replace the row on each iteration with your compute data frame. `df[iteration_index, ] <- iteration_output`.

Comment: What about just adding Rainfall Region as a column value in each run of the loop? Then your data is in standard "long" format, and you can easily transform to "wide" if you need to using `tidyr::spread`. If you have multiple files, you can just `rbind()` them all together.

Answer (score 0):

This is a toy example:

```
# create a data frame with the number of rows equal to the number of
# index iteration (in this case 3). The variable must be of the same type
# of your iteration output.
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = rep("some", 3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
some_text <- c("dog", "cat", "duck")

for (i in 1:3) {
  x <-  i + 10
  y <-  some_text[i]
  iteration_output <- data.frame(x, y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  # replace each variable of the given index row from the iteration output
  df[i, "x"] <- iteration_output$x
  df[i, "y"] <- iteration_output$y
}

df
```